# What is wrong with this 'ALTER TABLE' command?

Tags: sql, oracle-apex, alter-table

Here is the command;

```
ALTER TABLE product 
    ADD CONSTRAINT prod_cust_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (cust_id) REFERENCES  customer (cust_id) ENABLE;

ALTER TABLE product 
    ADD CONSTRAINT prod_sto_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (sto_id) REFERENCES  bakery (sto_id) ENABLE;

ALTER TABLE product 
    ADD CONSTRAINT prod_sup_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (sup_id) REFERENCES  supplier (sup_id) ENABLE;

CREATE INDEX prod_cust_ix ON product (cust_id);
CREATE INDEX prod_sto_ix ON product (sto_id);
CREATE INDEX prod_sup_ix ON product (sup_id);
```

The result:

> "ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_210200", line 673
>
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_210200", line 659
> ORA-06512: at "APEX_210200.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 1829
>
> REFERENCES  bakery (sto_id) ENABLE;
>
> ALTER TABLE  product ADD CONSTRAINT prod_sup_fk FOREIGN KEY (sup_id)
> REFERENCES  supplier (sup_id) ENABLE;
>
> CREATE INDEX  prod_cust_ix ON  product (cust_id);
>
> CREATE INDEX  prod_sto_ix ON  product (sto_id);"

The table product

```
CREATE TABLE product
(
   prod_id    VARCHAR2(10) CONSTRAINT prod_id_nn NOT NULL ENABLE,
   prod_price NUMBER(3, 2) CONSTRAINT prod_price_nn NOT NULL ENABLE,
   prod_avail VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT prod_avail_nn NOT NULL ENABLE,
   prod_mdate DATE CONSTRAINT prod_mdate_nn NOT NULL ENABLE,
   prod_edate DATE CONSTRAINT prod_edate_nn NOT NULL ENABLE,
   cust_id    NUMBER(4, 0),
   sto_id     VARCHAR(8) CONSTRAINT sto_id_nn NOT NULL ENABLE,
   sup_id     VARCHAR(10),

   CONSTRAINT prod_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (prod_id) USING INDEX ENABLE,
   CONSTRAINT prod_date_interval CHECK (prod_edate > prod_mdate) ENABLE
```

Table customer

```
CREATE TABLE  customer
(
    cust_id NUMBER(4,0) CONSTRAINT cust_id_nn NOT NULL ENABLE,
    cust_name VARCHAR2(500),
    cust_phone NUMBER(20),
    cust_add VARCHAR2(1000),
    cust_email VARCHAR2(400),
    CONSTRAINT customer_cust_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (cust_id) ENABLE 
);
```

Table bakery

```
CREATE TABLE bakery
(
     sto_id VARCHAR(8),
     sto_phone NUMBER(20) CONSTRAINT sto_phone_nn NOT NULL ENABLE,
     sto_add VARCHAR2(500) CONSTRAINT sto_add_nn NOT NULL ENABLE,
     sto_email VARCHAR2(400) CONSTRAINT sto_email_nn NOT NULL ENABLE,
     CONSTRAINT sto_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (sto_id) USING INDEX  ENABLE
);
```

Table supplier

```
CREATE TABLE supplier
(
    sup_id VARCHAR2(10) CONSTRAINT sup_id_nn NOT NULL ENABLE,
    sup_name VARCHAR2(500) CONSTRAINT sup_name_NN NOT NULL ENABLE,
    sup_add VARCHAR2(500) CONSTRAINT sup_add_nn NOT NULL ENABLE,
    CONSTRAINT sup_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (sup_id) USING INDEX  ENABLE
);
```

I'm using Oracle APEX 21.2.0

Comment: You product table is missing `);` to terminate the expression but, other than that, all the `ALTER TABLE` statements all work [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c16f1dedcfdf54e353a464a936efb9f6)

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to run all six statements as a single command - [kind of like this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9af20bad361a780cc065cc8a61d044a7)?

Comment: @MT0 Oops, I just missed copy that. Mine does include that and it works.  But the alter table statements in your link still cannot run I tried?

Comment: @AlexPoole I created the above tables first just like in the order, one by one create table statement. Then, I typed the above alter table statement.

Comment: @1ADMFRDS' - but you don't have *one* alter table statement; you have three alter table and three create index statements. Your error output is strange but suggests you're running them all as a single call, expecting that to be treated as six statements automatically. In other words - what happens if you *only* run one alter statement on its own? (Possibly, depending on how you do it, without the trailing semicolon - which is a statement separator.)

Comment: @AlexPoole How is one alter table statement like for these three statements? So, I ran them each without changing anything and no errors! Hmm, the wonders.. The thing is, I am going to need all the statements I ran compiled into a script and just run them fine

Comment: The three alters are all against the same table so you could combine those into one. You can't combine the three index creations though, or combine them with the alter. I guess you could make them all dynamic statements within an anonymous PL/SQL block, but that's messy. Why can't you just run them one by one; or as a script through SQL\*Plus?

Comment: @AlexPoole Meaning only one Alter Table statement at the beginning for all three statements? Tried that and still unable to run. The reason that I am running Create and Alter (including Insert Into Values) one by one table is to check for errors easier if any. Not running them all at one go and many errors jumbled up that I would not know which is it. I need all the statements working to then compile as a script to make an app consisting of those statements. I am required to use Oracle APEX for this.

Comment: @AlexPoole  I am not sure if from all those statements that ran one by one can be collected to make as one app not separate apps in Oracle APEX